# _reactNAtiveRouterFLux.Actions.EmployeeEdit is not a function

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am learning react-native through udemy course. While building the application I am getting this error although I am following all the steps

I tried to make some changes in the code or either find any online solutions but nothing worked

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Text, TouchableWithoutFeedback, View } from 'react-native';
    import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
    import { CardSection } from './Common';


    class ListItem extends Component {

        onRowPress() {
          Actions.EmployeeEdit({ employee: this.props.employee });

        }
      render() {
       const { name } = this.props.employee;

        return (
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.onRowPress.bind(this)}>
            <View>
              <CardSection>
                <Text style={styles.titleStyle}>
                  {name}
                </Text>
              </CardSection>
            </View>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        );
      }
    }

    const styles = {
      titleStyle: {
        fontSize: 18,
        paddingLeft: 15,
        flex: 1
      }
    }

    export default ListItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Actions.EmployeeEdit**

There is no such function in the **Actions** of `real-native-ruter-flux`.

If you want to push the scene to the stack and convert it to a new one,

```js
Actions.push({ employee: this.props.employee });
```

if you want Pops the navigation stack until the Scene with the specified key is reached.

```js
Actions.popTo({ employee: this.props.employee })
```

Comment: No I don't want either push or pop . This employeeEdit is function mapping into an employee list to get their data

Comment: There is no function of that name in real-native-ruter-flux action. Are you saying you're making it and using it yourself?